# Excel Date Countifs

Tags: excel, countif

I need to count all dates that are "less than" today to see which work is overdue. I understand that this can be done simply with

```
=countif(F:F,"<"&TODAY())
```

However, the dates in Column F are formatted like "12/05 - Evening" instead of just "12/05". Because of this, the formula is not picking up anything. Does anyone know how to change this code so that it counts any cell that contains dates prior to today, even if there is other text in the cell? I've tried playing around with these "**", but can't get it to work.. Thank You!

Comment: Use a helper column and separate the date out then use the countif() on that column.

Answer (score 1):

So based on my comment I would get the date by using left() with find() like so:

```
LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

Then format as short date and it behave as a date.

From comment:
Use a helper column and separate the date out then use the countif() on that column